# Floating Ad doesn't working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, doctype

I'm working with a floating ad but it doesn't working in IE but FF does.

actually I found the issue, that was doctype issue its html transitional type and when it change to xhtml it'll work smoothly.

Im not sure what to do, I cant change that doctype, it causes lots of alignment issues throughout my site, so is there any solutions..?

hope to get replies....

Paul

Comment: Fix your alignment issues. Transitional is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works when you change the DOCTYPE is that you're going into (probably; maybe out of, but I don't know what your exact doctype strings look like) "quirks mode".

That's actually a fundamental decision you need to make about your pages anyway.  You almost certainly be working in "standards compliant mode", which is (more or less) the alternative of "quirks mode". Running in quirks mode means literally that you're asking for old-style buggy behavior. And it's not just IE — other browsers may also act oddly when not in standards mode.